# How to set up Node.js server with cookie based KeyCloak authentication - getting infinite redirects now

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I'm setting up a Node.js server that is protected by KeyCloak. This is the first time I'm using KeyCloak, I'm experimenting with various use-cases.

I successfully implemented the scenario where I use `express-session` and `MemoryStore` with a public client. Here is my `keycloak.json`:

```js
{
  "realm": "keycloak-node-monolith",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "keycloak-node-monolith-public",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Here is my working server code:

```js
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'uhlulululu',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

var keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });

app.use( keycloak.middleware());

app.get( '/check-sso', keycloak.checkSso(), (req, res) => {
    res.send('Check sso success');
});

app.get( '/protected', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
   res.send('Protected content visible to you, because you are authenticated.');
});

app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0', () => {console.log('App listening on port 3000');});
```

**I'm having trouble to change the above working code to use cookies instead of MemoryStore.**

My `keycloak.json` is the same as above, it's working, so I see no reason to change it.

I applied the following changes in my code:

- I initialize KeyCloak with `{ cookies: true }`. I'm pretty confident this is a good move, this will make `keycloak-connect` use the built-in `CookieStore`.
- I added `cookieParser` to make cookies available.
- I tried adding `cookie-session` or `express-session`, otherwise I'm getting an error about missing `session.id`.

This is my code now:

```js
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var express = require('express');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser('secret123'));

//app.use(session({
//  secret: 'secret123',
//  resave: false,
//  saveUninitialized: true,
//  cookie: {}
//));

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  secret: 'secret123',
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
}));

//https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.0/html-single/securing_applications_and_services_guide/index#applicationclustering
var keycloak = new Keycloak({ cookies: true });

app.use( keycloak.middleware());

app.get( '/check-sso', keycloak.checkSso(), (req, res) => {
    res.send('Check sso success');
});

app.get( '/protected', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
   res.send('Protected content visible to you, because you are authenticated!');
});

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {console.log('App listening on port 3000');});
```

When I visit `localhost:3000/protected`, I'm getting redirected to KeyCloak and I can authenticate successfully. Then I'm redirected to `localhost:3000/protected`, the Cookies are created and passed to the server.

**What I'm seeing after authentication is an endless redirect loop that looks like this:**
[image]

I've read many sources online, this repo https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/lib/keyCloakService.js is the one that has a cookie based stateless solution, but it re-implements various features of `keycloak-connect`.

I'd rather prefer a simple solution that can be directly plugged in into `keycloak-connect`, if this is possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes and No; I moved my MVP to Firebase.